# Parse a line to get the required content

Tags: java, regex

```
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="T">2</int><lst name="params"><str name="echoParams">all</str><str name="Params">all</str>solrpingquery<str name="ty">standard</str></lst></lst><str name="status">OK</str>
```

Above is the line that I want to parse and I want to extract **OK** from the above line. Means from this below particular string I want to extract **OK**. **OK** can be anything, it is not mandatory that status will be **OK**.

```
<str name="status">OK</str>
```

What is the fast way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like valid XML, so I'd suggest an XML parser (hard to say which one since you didn't say which language you're using).

A regex approach could look like

```
<str name="status">(.*?)</str>
```

or

```
<str name="status">([^<>]*)</str>
```

But you still need to specify which language you're using, so I can adjust the regex to its needs. And there are several problems with trying to match (X)ML with regexes, so it might not always work as desired. As long as there's only normal text between the tag, it should be OK, though.

In Java:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("<str name=\"status\">(.*?)</str>");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    ResultString = regexMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed description. I am working with Java. How can we use this regex example with Java

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit that I'm anti-XML and anti-regex when it is overkill.  How about

```
static final String SEARCH_STRING = "<str name=\"status\">";
```

then, somewhere

```
int idx1 = theString.indexOf(SEARCH_STRING );
int idx2 = theString.indexOf("<", idx1+1 );
// verify that both are >= 0;
String result = theString.substring(idx1 +SEARCH_STRING.length(), idx2);
```

NOTE - I'm pretty sure there is an off by 1 error somewhere in that code, so check it.